# changing pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, navigator

I'm trying to program an app with flutter, but I'm not getting whats the best way to change pages, I'd like to have a bottom navigation bar to change between pages, but I would also want to be able to change page by scrolling on the left or right, and I also want to have a button on the app bar to switch to a separate page, I'm not getting if I should use the navigator or the pageview, and if I have to use the navigator, should each page have its own scaffold? because I tried that way but I don't like the fact that every time not only the page changes but also the bottom nav bar and the app bar, thanks!

Comment: You can use this package for your use case.
https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question has a lot of tutorials and documents.
for using the bottom navigation bar with scrollable for moving each page is using **TabBar** widget

You can put **TabBar** widget on **bottomNavigationBar** properties inside **Scaffold** and wrap **TabBar** with **Container** for giving a background color.

**TabBar** widget have **isScrollable** properties to able move each page by scrolling.
Example:

> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_name/structure.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Structure(),
      );
  }
}
```

create new dart file

> structure.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_name/homepage.dart';
import 'package:app_name/searchpage.dart';
import 'package:app_name/notificationpage.dart';

class Structure extends StatefulWidget {
  const Structure({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StructureState createState() => _StructureState();
}

class _StructureState extends State<Structure> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;
  TabController _controller;

  final _pages = [
    HomePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    NotificationPage(),
    // add any page class
  ];

  final _bottomBarItems = [
    Tab(text: "Home", icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
    Tab(text: "Search", icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
    Tab(text: "Notif", icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
    // add any icon for each page class on bottom bar navigation
  ];

  void onTapBar(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    _controller.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
        // drawer widget for build separate page u want
        // with hamburger icon in App Bar
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: _pages[_currentTabIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: TabBar(
          isScrollable: false,
          // set isScrollable to true
          // if you want to able move the page by scrolling 
          controller: _controller,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black87,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
          labelColor: Colors.red.shade700,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3),
          insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 40, 0)),
          tabs: _bottomBarItems,
       ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Note: you need to set isScrollable to **true**

---

for each page, you can write with Stateless or Stateful widget class with new dart file

for example

> homepage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HoomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}
```

For the separate page you want, you can use **drawer** properties inside Scaffold widget.
you can check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRj86iHihgY) for build a **Drawer** widget